# 追従する文字列を、"ボタン"ではなくてただクリックするだけで"切り離し⇔追従"とする方法

Tags: javascript

最近、追従する文字列をクリックするたびに"切り離し⇔追従"とする面白いコードをいただき、
これをヒントに別コードで"ボタン"をクリックするたびに"切り離し⇔追従"とするコードを作りました。
これを、"ボタン"ではなくて、いただいたコードのようにただ"クリック"するだけで"切り離し⇔追従"とするコードに作り変えられないでしょうか。可能でしたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。
関連箇所は、スクリプトの"function onoff(){}"あたりです。

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="clock">
        <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
            <div style="position:relative">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
            <div style="position:relative">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
            <div style="position:relative">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
            <div style="position:relative">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
            <div style="position:relative">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="時計Off" id="control">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        "use strict";

    function $(sel)
    {
        return document.getElementById(sel);
    }

    function $$(sel)
    {
        if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
        {
            return document.getElementsByName(sel);
        }

        return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
    }


    var dCol = '00ff00', //date colour.
        sCol = 'ff0000', //seconds colour.
        mCol = '000000', //minutes colour.
        hCol = '000000', //hours colour.
        fCol = '0000ff', //face color
        ClockHeight = 40,
        ClockWidth = 40,
        ClockFromMouseY = 0,
        ClockFromMouseX = 100,
        d = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        m = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],    
        date = new Date(),
        day = date.getDate(),
        year = date.getYear() + 1900;

    var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " "+  day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
    var D = TodaysDate.split('');

    var H = '...';
        H = H.split('');
    var M = '....';
        M = M.split('');
    var S = '.....';
        S = S.split('');
    var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
        font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
        size = 1,
        speed = 0.6;
        Face = Face.split(' ');
    var n = Face.length;
    var a = size * 10;
    var ymouse = 0,
        xmouse = 0,
        scrll = 0,
        props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
        props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
    var Split = 360 / n;
    var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
    var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
    var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
    var HandY = -7,
        HandX = -2.5,
        step = 0.06,
        currStep = 0,
        y = [],
        x = [],
        Y = [],
        X = [],
        Dy = [],
        Dx = [],
        DY = [],
        DX = [];

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        y[i] = 0;
        x[i] = 0;
        Y[i] = 0;
        X[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
    {
        Dy[i] = 0;
        Dx[i] = 0;
        DY[i] = 0;
        DX[i] = 0;
    }

    var wrapper = $('clock');
    var html = '';

    // Date wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


    // Face wrapper
    html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
    }
    $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

    // Hours wrapper
    html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
    } 
    $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

    // Minute wrapper
    html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
    } 
    $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

    // Seconds wrapper
    html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
    } 
    $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

    // Mouse move event handler
    function Mouse(evnt) 
    {
        if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
        {
            ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
            xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
        }
        else
        {
            ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
            xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
        }


    }
    document.onmousemove = Mouse;

    function ClockAndAssign() 
    {
        var time = new Date();
        var secs = time.getSeconds();
        var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
        var mins = time.getMinutes();
        var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
        var hr = time.getHours();
        var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
        $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
        $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
        $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
        $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
        $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var F = $$('Face')[i];
            F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
            F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
        {
            var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
            HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
            HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
        {
            var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
            ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
            ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
        {
            var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
            SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
            SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
        {
            var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
            DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
            DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
        }
        currStep -= step;
    }

    function Delay() 
    {
        scrll = 0;
        Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
        Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);
        for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
            Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
            Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
        }
        y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
        x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
            x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
        }
        ClockAndAssign();
    var tim=setTimeout(Delay, 20);
    if (!vis){clearTimeout(tim)}
    }

    var vis=true;
    function onoff(){
    vis=!vis;
    document.getElementById("control").value=vis?"時計Off":"時計On";
    if (vis){Delay();}
    }
    document.getElementById("control").onclick=onoff;

    Delay();

    }());
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"ボタン”をクリックするのでなく、"ウィンドウ"上をクリックすると考えて、
function onoff(){}内を以下のように書けば、希望通りになりました。
まず、*input*タグを消し、以下のように書き換えるだけでいいです。

```
var vis=true;//スイッチ
function onoff(){
vis=!vis;
if (vis){Delay();}
}
window.onclick=onoff;

Delay();
```

また、時計を"フリーズ"させないで、動いたまま切り離したいときは、以下のように書くといいです。

```
function Delay() 
{中略 
        ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

var vis=true;//スイッチ
function onoff(){
vis=!vis;
document.onmousemove=vis? Mouse:null;
}
window.onclick=onoff;
Delay();
```